# How to prevent focusing on specific inputs

Tags: jquery, recursion

Right now, I have no idea about how to do what I want..

Let's say I have a form and some special fields whose value is calculated automatically. Those fields (inputs) have a special class named ... 'calculate'.

When the user clicks on one of those inputs, I would like the focus to go away to the next valid input (an input with no calculate class)

I thought that would be enough but no :

```
$('input.calculate').bind('focus', function() {
    var inputs = $(this).closest('form').find(':input');
    inputs.eq( inputs.index(this)+ 1 ).focus();
});
```

this misbehaviour occurs when several inputs whose class is calculate are next to each others : the cursor goes to the next input even though the next input has a calculate class.

it is quite normal, thinking about it, as this function behaves like a recursive function.

Somebody has an idea to do what I want to do ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to use `disabled` attribute to disable them. So the user cannot select them (focus at them).

Or by jQuery you can do this:

```
$('.calculate').focus(function () { // note the focus event; not click
  $(this).next('input').focus(); // set focus to next one!
}
```

This will set focus to the next element with no class `.calculate`. This event is usefull since it will trigger when the input is being focused and not clicked!

Comment: You are right, but disable does not accept the style I put on those fields

Comment: The second one does not work for me... next works if the input is just after... it is not the case here